# Is "release" countable when used to mean "to let go" or "to make available"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

Is "release" a count noun or mass noun in the meaning of "let someone or something out of a place"? I see conflicting information from different dictionaries, even within the same dictionary.

MacMillan defines it as uncountable:

> [UNCOUNTABLE]
>   *The release of Nelson Mandela was watched by millions of people on TV.*
>   *We’re doing all we can to prevent the release of toxic waste into the oceans.*
>   *the release of secret government information*

But the same usage is defined in Cambridge Dictionary as countable or singular. I saw this line on the Internet, which seems to suggest it is countable:

> A judicial mandate to a prison official ordering a prisoner be brought to court in order to determine imprisonment or **a release** from legal custody. ([source](https://docslide.us/amp/education/why-the-american-legal-system-is-unique.html))

But there are also other examples that suggest otherwise. Is "release" countable in this definition? What about in this following sentence? Can it be pluralized?

> We knew that the game’s release was imminent.

Comment: As with many things, context is critical. It can either be a countable *or* a mass noun depending on how it's used.

Answer (score 1):

As countable:
- There were 10 political prisoner **releases** last year. [possible though awkward]

- There were ten dam (water) **releases** on the river last week.
- There were 50 **album releases** at that company.

As uncountable:
- **Release of prisoners** can only be negotiated by lawyers.

**It could be argued that the Nelson Mandela release example is used "uncountably"**.

If a person is released from prison twice, you wouldn't generally say releases. You would say:

He was released from prison twice. That's the kind of logic they are using to say release is uncountable in this particular context.